# Weblogic 12c - EJB Timer Service not working with MDB

Tags: java, timer, ejb, weblogic12c

I am upgrading the application from Weblogic 11g to 12c with JDK 1.7. We have EJB Timers used within an MDB and this doesn't seem to work in Weblogic 12c. I created a standalone application just to see if the timer is getting fired but it doesnt work within MDB. The same code works for Session Bean. Any idea of why it is not working with MDB? I dont see any error in the logs but the @Timeout annotated method is never getting called. Did anybody face this issue?